# trying to create a workbook that will process information in 5 different daily xlsx files every day

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

good day to all.

i have joined a business where a java platform generates 5 different xlsx reports every day which are then processed by hand to create one standardized daily summary for management in another xlsx file. all this work takes hours and can lead to errors.

i want to create an excel or google sheets master file which will contain formulas that can read the latest files that have been generated and automatically sort and query the contents as necessary to generate the final summary.

first i need to decide whether to use excel or google sheets (or any other free to use spreadsheet program) for this purpose. i think that it could be possible to create 5 different folders for this information, one for each of the 5 different report types, and then have formulas in the master workbook that will locate and process the latest file copied to each (or formulas that can process any xlsx file that one has selected by hand). from what i have read so far, tools like power query or auto update could possibly be deployed for this objective.

i will then need to learn several spreadsheet commands to sort and query the information as necessary. i'm ready to read any tutorials or examples necessary and i will greatly appreciate any suggestions and advice from experienced users.

i'm pretty sure these tasks can indeed be automated as the xlsx files for the reports have the exact same data types, columns and formats every day.

[sample file.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSegdqSgbifszpIkm0PhAiegTytAtaWGQr4Gc8ZbXUiY_0e6uPTCQ6zFiiuSGC0RWw1_c-jgz82_nVP/pubhtml)

thus, my question would be, ¿would it be more advisable to use excel or google sheets for this kind of " adaptive " master workbook? so far i only have the daily xlsx report files and have been reading which would be the best methodology to follow for this objective.  thanks to all, regards.

Comment: In my eyes Power BI should do it...

Comment: thanks a lot. i have taken a look and power bi could be promising, however i have also realized that i do not have permissions to install software and could not export data easily, either.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you described, both Excel and Google Sheets could be used to achieve your goal. However, there are some key differences between the two that might influence your decision:

Excel:

- Excel’s Power Query is a powerful tool for importing data from various sources, including .xlsx files. It can refresh data automatically when the file is opened or at specified intervals.
- Excel has robust data analysis and visualization tools, which might be beneficial depending on the complexity of your reports.
- Excel is not free, but it’s included in the Microsoft Office suite, which your organization might already have.

Google Sheets:

- Google Sheets can also import data from various sources, including
  .xlsx files, using the `IMPORTDATA`, `IMPORTHTML`, `IMPORTXML`, etc.
  functions. However, these functions have some limitations and might
  not be as powerful as Excel’s Power Query.
- Google Sheets is free andweb-based, which allows for easy sharing and collaboration.
- Google Apps Script can be used to automate tasks in Google Sheets, but it
  requires some knowledge of JavaScript.

In conclusion, if your
organization already has Microsoft Office, and the reports require
complex data analysis, Excel might be the better choice due to its
advanced features. On the other hand, if cost is a concern, or if you
need to share and collaborate on the reports easily, Google Sheets
would be a good option.

For learning spreadsheet commands, both Excel and Google Sheets have
extensive documentation and tutorials available online.

Remember, the best tool often depends on your specific needs and circumstances.

Comment: thank you very much. excel or excel 365 will be the instruments of choice for the reasons you have kindly mentioned. i have never used power query or very complex commands but i'm sure i should be able to manufacture this workbook as required by relying on online resources.